# Parse XML POST data with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, post, rexml

I'm using REXML to parse through some XML data sent via POST. The XML is sent correctly formatted with "&" sent as "`&amp;`". However, when I try to parse it, I had problems like the `&amp;` becoming & and throwing an error. I fixed with gsub, but now it says `#<REXML::ParseException: Missing end tag for 'br'`

Anyone have any experience parsing through XML sent via POST on Rails?

```
def parse
xml = params["xml_data"]

xml = xml.gsub(/&/,"&amp;")

doc, posts = REXML::Document.new(xml), []
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most likely is that you send html istead of xml and html isn't valid xml - don't try to use regexp or xml processors for its parsing. In your case you likely encountered <br> tag (not <br /> pay attention) - that perfectly ok for html. Try to use [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) gem for html parsing

Comment: Yeah I just discovered Nokogiri. Its so nice. Excited to try it out. I just installed the gem and added it to my gemfile, but am getting no such file to load -- nokogiri ... now off to figuring why it wont load the nokogiri gem!